# if syntax for dbnull and value

Tags: vb.net

I need to make something like :

```
if isdbnull(value) or value = something then
'do something
else
'do something else
end if
```

of course i get an error using this method , so my question is how do i rewrite it to avoid the "operator not defined for dbnull and something" error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few approaches to this, and which you use may depend on the values you're working with.  However, if you want something that catches all conditions then I'd do this:

```
If Value Is Nothing OrElse IsDbNull(value) Then
  'do something
Else
  'do something else
End If
```

This will check if the Value is nothing, which can sometimes happen without the value actually being DBNull.

But the most important part of this is the OrElse.  OrElse is the short-circuiting operator which terminates the evaluation of the condition as soon as the runtime knows what the outcome will be.  By contrast, the Or operator will execute the entire condition no matter what, and that is the reason your original code fails.

EDIT:

Now that I look at your example code again, I can see how my NotNull() function may help you:

```
Public Shared Function NotNull(Of T)(ByVal Value As T, ByVal DefaultValue As T) As T
    If Value Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Value) Then
        Return DefaultValue
    Else
        Return Value
    End If
End Function
```

Usage:

```
if NotNull(value, something) = something then
'do something
else
'do something else
end if
```

Comment: I'm hot sure this is exactly what the question is asking for, but the key is the "OrElse" part for sure.

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Actually now that I look at your original code again, I can see how my NotNull function may help you.

Comment: yes, it's a very clever solution that NotNull function, thanks again

Comment: Jimmy, I think you're right.  I had to look at it again to understand the intention of the example code, but my latest "edit" addresses that.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use the OrElse, AndAlso operators

```
If IsDBnull(value) OrElse value = something Then
    ''#do something
Else
    ''#do something else
End If
```

The shortcuts operator means the rest of the If conditions won't be executed if the first is true.

Edit: Steve beat me to it while I was formatting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
value Is DBNull.Value
```

Comment: i still get Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and string "something".

Answer (score -1):

value is nothing

Comment: no, the problem is in the "or value = something " part, that's what is causing the exception